# connecting sql server from windows ce application through Activesync without being on network

Tags: sql-server, connection, windows-ce, wmdc

I've connected my Motorola MC3090R having Windows CE 5 through cradle (Windows Mobile Device Center) with my laptop having Windows 7 (there is no network), my question is that how i will connect to sql server (it's on my laptop) from my handheld app? what will be my connection string inside my handheld app? as there is no network what ip i will use in the connection string?

please help

Comment: Does this help? http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this connection string.

```
m_Desktopconn = New SqlConnection(
  "Data Source=192.168.55.100,1433;Initial Catalog=Testing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa;")
```

I had two instances MYPC\SQL2005 & MYPC\SQL2008, and then installed SQL 2005 Express on MYPC (Without instance)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "connected through cradle" I assume you are using Active Sync on the device. If that is the case, you will have a dynamic IP address assigned to your connection, in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461957/get-ip-address-of-host-pc-from-windows-mobile-when-connected-via-activesync) you will find how to retrieve this address so that you can use it to build the connection string.

Comment: Dear yms,

I've tried

System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList(0) its giving me

{System.Net.IPAddress}

    Address: 1698146496

    AddressFamily: InterNetwork {2}

    Any: {System.Net.IPAddress}

    Broadcast: {System.Net.IPAddress}

    IPv6Any: {System.Net.IPAddress}

    IPv6Loopback: {System.Net.IPAddress}

    IPv6None: {System.Net.IPAddress}

    Loopback: {System.Net.IPAddress}

    None: {System.Net.IPAddress}

    ScopeId: {"The attempted operation is not supported for the type 
of object referenced"}

there is no ip for PC

Comment: by the way i am using Windows Mobile Device Center with my laptop having Windows 7 without network

Comment: And you are using 'System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList(0) ' from the device, within your WinCE application, right?

Comment: yes sir from my windows ce app and even i put
<br>
        `For Each obj As Object In System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
            MessageBox.Show("")
        Next`
<br>
which is just running once and showing the above detail


 {System.Net.IPAddress} Address: 1698146496 .......

Comment: Got it working!

m_Desktopconn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.55.100,1433;Initial Catalog=Testing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa;")

first i had two instances MYPC\SQL2005 & MYPC\SQL2008

then i install SQL2005Express on MYPC (Without instance)

and nows it is working fine.

Thank you all for your kind support & time,

God bless us all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup

PDA -> PC ->Sql Server(Remote).

If that's the setup you can configure via the Windows Mobile Device Center.

1. Connect the device to your PC
2. Open Windows Mobile Device Center
3. Click on Mobile Device Settings
4. Connection Settings.
5. Select 'The Internet' on the combo 'This computer is connected to:'

Comment: Thanks Quijano i will try this, but what will be the server name or ip address in the connection string because i won't have any network connect to the end user desktop, i mean if there will be no network then how my windows ce app connect using connection string?

Comment: Got it working!

m_Desktopconn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.55.100,1433;Initial Catalog=Testing;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa;")

first i had two instances MYPC\SQL2005 & MYPC\SQL2008

then i install SQL2005Express on MYPC (Without instance)

and nows it is working fine.

Thank you all for your kind support & time,

God bless us all.

Comment: Whenever I try to connect the sql server from device it is showing some connection error, let me also try this

Comment: thank you! I can also select "work network" which allows me to connect to the sql server on my local domain. This solved my connectivity problem that I was fighting against for two days straight.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void form1Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String strConnection =
                "Data Source=your_ip;Initial Catalog=your_database;Integrated Security=True; User ID=your_db_user;Password=your_db_password;";

        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("You Success!!");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You failed!" + ex.Message);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```