# SQL Server ConnectionString for Windows CE App

Tags: sql-server, windows-ce, wmdc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [connecting sql server from windows ce application through Activesync without being on network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846591/connecting-sql-server-from-windows-ce-application-through-activesync-without-bein)

What will be my connection string inside my Windows CE app for sql server 2008, if my pc is standalone/not on network

I've following scenario

Desktop: Windows 7 having SQL Server 2008
Connectivity through:  Windows Mobile Device Center - USB Cradle
Handheld: Windows CE 5
NO NETWORK Just the Handheld connected via USB Cradle to my PC

or if it is not possible without network to access a sql server then what will be the solution?

Please help I'm stuck very badly